# What is the Biblical Basis for the belief that Christ's death was not for everyone (The notion called Limited Atonement)?

Tags: biblical-basis, reformed-theology, atonement, limited-atonement

Im not asking for an overview of different denominations' views, but rather scriptural evidence for the view held by Calvinists that Christ's death was not for everyone.

I'm very familiar with alleged 5 points of Calvinism, - which were not written by Calvin. I've searched the scriptures, using online concordances, dictionaries and multiple webforums, but I'm not able to find a single verse anywhere that says "Christ only died for some, but not all", or a verse that says "His death was not for everyone."

While I'm happy for anyone to give a verse or Biblical support, I am especially interested to hear from people who actually believes this- or can help me understand what special term I should be looking for?

Comment: I've merged this into our existing question. Please ask how the doctrine is compatible with specific verses as follow up questions. (And please make one question for each such verse.)